# Not being able to catch POST variable in a PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Given below is the ajax call from the javascript

```
let dataX = {"VERSION": "iVersion_100", "ITOKEN": "iToken", "METHOD":"GSB"};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "target.php",
        data: dataX,
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Now, here is the simple target.php

```
<?php ob_start();
$iVersion = $_REQUEST['VERSION'];
$iToken = $_REQUEST['ITOKEN'];
$iMethod = $_REQUEST['METHOD'];
echo $iVersion;
?>
```

I was expecting to see "iVersion_100" in the console log. Instead, it is returning NULL. I have almost broken the wall with my head banging. Request your help desperately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check $_POST['VERSION']

Comment: have tried that too... Not happening.

Comment: Check network  tab for POST headers

Comment: that looks fine - odd though, when I test your code I see the developer tools networks tab looks fine, but nothing in the console at all!

Comment: Could be me, but shouldn't json be decoded before you can use it like that? Try removing `dataType: "json"` and you should see the magic at work.

Comment: ahh .. json!!! the php isn't returning JSON!!

Comment: Status code: 200. All OK.

Comment: if you add a .error handler like - `.error(function() {
                        console.log(arguments);
                })` - you'll get the error `"JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"` - because your PHP isn't sending JSON

Comment: No... If i echo "1"; it does return. So something other than json, i guess

Comment: add a .error handler to handle errors

Comment: That's because there is no error really. Since JSON must be decoded before PHP can use it, your `$_REQUEST[]` variables basicly don't exist. So it's filling your variables with empty strings and eventually just returns an empty string.

Comment: if you add an error handler you'll see there is an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `dataType: "json"`

but the PHP responds with `iVersion_100`

this is not valid JSON

as you have no `.error` handler, it seems jQuery "silently ignores" this error condition and the end result is that `.done` is **never called**

change your code to

```
            let dataX = {"VERSION": "iVersion_100", "ITOKEN": "iToken", "METHOD":"GSB"};

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "target.php",
                    data: dataX,
                    dataType: "json"
            })
            .error(function() {
                    console.log(arguments);
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                    console.log('hello');
                    console.log(data);
            });
```

You'll see there **is** an error, `"JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"`

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be a forward movement. WIll work on this. Will get back in case of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `dataType: "json"` in this code your are telling ajax to get return data in json format.

In place of sending data in json  your are just `echo $iVersion;` echo the data. If you want to use json as dataType please parse data before output it like this `echo json_encode($iVersion);` and you will get the data.

Or

If you want to use simple out put in none json format please Remove `dataType: "json"` from ajax attribute. You will get the output `echo $iVersion;`.